# Get logged in username from script launched by launchdeamon

Tags: macos, bash, launchd

I am trying to find the current (logged in) users name. The script looks for a particular user and changes the network configuration.

The script is started by a LaunchDeamon in `/Library/LaunchDeamons`.

I am not able to find a way to get the users name who is logging, so if I login as Tom when I call the script the username is root.

Can one one suggest a way to get Tom?

Answer (score 2):

OS X allows multiple users to be logged in at the same time. If you are trying to get the name of active console user, the script given below might help.

```
LOGGED_IN_USER=`stat -f%Su /dev/console`
```

Answer (score 1):

A LaunchDaemon is a system process. It may run when no one is logged in. If you want something that runs in a user's context, you likely want a LaunchAgent instead.

Note that "the current (logged in) user" is somewhat poorly defined because there may be fast user switching (so multiple logged in users), and users may login without a GUI session (via SSH for instance). If you use a LaunchAgent, there may be multiple copies running (and if no user is logged in, there may be no copies running).

For your example, you may just be looking to fetch current login session information (though remember, if you're a LaunchDaemon, then there may be no login session currently). This is best described in [Multiple User Environment Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPMultipleUsers/Concepts/FastUserSwitching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002209-104219). In particular, look at "Getting Login Session Information."

In some cases it may be preferable to let a central system daemon communicate with per-session agents. One easy technique for that is `NSDistributedNotification`, particularly if data only needs to go in one direction. If you need more complex interactions between a system daemon and the user sessions, you should investigate XPC services, which are designed for that kind of problem. See "Creating XPC Services" in the [Daemons and Service Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html).

System-level programming, especially things involving user sessions, is exceedingly subtle on OS X (particularly compared to Linux). You should study the Daemons and Services Programming Guide carefully before undertaking it. Things that sound very simple turn out to have many corner cases and surprises. Fast user switching, non-local accounts, mounted home directories, privilege separation (particularly post-10.7), the incredibly vagaries of launchd.... It's all quite manageable, but definitely important to spend some study time before diving in.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot as launch daemon runs in the system context and not user context.

As per Apple: 
Most daemons run in the system context of the system—that is, they run at the lowest level of the system and make their services available to all user sessions. Daemons at this level continue running even when no users are logged into the system, so the daemon program should have no direct knowledge of users. Instead, the daemon must wait for a user program to contact it and make a request. As part of that request, the user program usually tells the daemon how to return any results.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you suggest a way I could run a sudo command as an agent for a non admin user? SO Tom is a domain user, but the command requires local admin?